# AppArmor: Unusual denied "name=<string>" message

Tags: permissions, apparmor

I have a custom AppArmor profile to confine Syncthing. *(I realise that this might not be a specific Ubuntu question, but I only use Ubuntu so I haven't seen if this affects other Linux distros).*

This is the profile:

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/syncthing {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  # Obviously needs Internet access to work.
  network raw,
  network inet,
  network inet6,

 # Access to execute binary
  /usr/bin/syncthing cx,

  # Wants read access to SOMAXCONN
  /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn r,

  # Needs to be able to read these to work properly
  /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf r,
  /etc/hosts r,
  /etc/host.conf r,
  /etc/nsswitch.conf r,
  /etc/ssl/certs/** r,
  /etc/mime.types r,
  /etc/gai.conf r,

  # Allow access to synced folders.
  owner @{HOME}/Documents/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/Documents/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/Pictures/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/Pictures/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/Public/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/Public/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/Music/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/Music/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/Downloads/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/Downloads/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.keys/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/.keys/** rwk,

  # Allow access to config files
  owner @{HOME}/.config/syncthing/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/syncthing/** rwk,

  # Silence warnings on things we don't want access to
  deny / r,
  deny /* r,
  deny @{HOME} r,

}
```

And this is the syslog message I've been getting recently:

```
Apr 16 11:07:05 supercomputer kernel: [ 1240.879568] audit: type=1400 audit(1460768825.434:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/syncthing" name=2F686F6D652F7365616E2F566964656F732F43616D65726120566964656F732F pid=2277 comm="syncthing" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Apr 16 11:16:28 supercomputer kernel: [ 1803.632950] audit: type=1400 audit(1460769388.508:32): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/syncthing" name=2F686F6D652F7365616E2F566964656F732F43616D65726120566964656F732F pid=2266 comm="syncthing" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Apr 16 11:26:13 supercomputer kernel: [ 2388.037482] audit: type=1400 audit(1460769973.246:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/syncthing" name=2F686F6D652F7365616E2F566964656F732F43616D65726120566964656F732F pid=1021 comm="syncthing" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Apr 16 11:36:56 supercomputer kernel: [ 3031.177125] audit: type=1400 audit(1460770616.751:34): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/syncthing" name=2F686F6D652F7365616E2F566964656F732F43616D65726120566964656F732F pid=2273 comm="syncthing" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Since I made the profile myself, I've become relatively familiar with AppArmor and the logs that it produces - but I've never seen this `name=2F686F6D652F7365616E2F566964656F732F43616D65726120566964656F732F` message before. It doesn't look to be a filepath, which is what AppArmor normally reports on.

What does this error message mean? How can I either allow it or deny it in the profile?

Comment: This message means that `apparmor` denied read access to `/usr/bin/syncthing`. Try to add `r` flag: `/usr/bin/syncthing cxr,` and reload profile `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.syncthing`

Comment: If it were denying access to `/usr/bin/syncthing`, wouldn't it say `name=/usr/bin/syncthing`?

Comment: Would it make sense to commit a version of that apparmor profile upstream?

Comment: Does Syncthing have an upstream AppArmor profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex string following "name=" is just a hex-encoded string of the path of the file you're looking for.  If you copy your hex string into the http://www.asciitohex.com/ in the "hexadecimal" box (or many equivalent sites) and click convert to get the original string back.  I won't post the exact string here to preserve your privacy -- just in case it matters.

If you don't want to use a third-party website, you can run a python shell and do the following:

```
x="2F.... (your string here)"
''.join(chr(int(x[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(x), 2))
```

I encountered this on Debian too.  I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never figured that out, it makes perfect sense now. The path name doesn't bother me - `/home/sean/Videos/Camera Videos/` is what it came out to be. Which, looking at it, isn't allowed in the AppArmor profile.